# How do I use ScrollEffect on a ListView to prevent overscrolling?

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am using the same way to prevwnt overscrolling of a TextView like that:

```
ScrollView:
    id: scrlv
    size_hint: (1, 1)
    effect_cls: ScrollEffect #avoid overscrolling
    TextInput:
        id: ro_log
        size_hint: (1, None)
        height: max(self.minimum_height, scrlv.height) #required to enable scrolling when list starts to grow
        readonly: True
        background_color: 0,0,0,0
        foreground_color: 1,1,1,1
```

But for a ListView, which contains a ScrollView, the kv spec below has no effect:

```
ListView:
    id: commandListView
    effect_cls: ScrollEffect #no effect !
    adapter: ListAdapter(data=[], cls=main.CommandListButton, args_converter=lambda row_index,rec: {'text':rec, 'on_press':root.commandSelected})
    height: '0dp'
    size_hint_y: None
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution, as SP SP gave it in his comment above:

```
ListView:
    id: commandListView
    adapter: ListAdapter(data=[], cls=main.CommandListButton, args_converter=lambda row_index,rec: {'text':rec, 'on_press':root.historyItemSelected})
    height: '0dp'
    size_hint_y: None
    on_parent: self.container.parent.effect_cls = ScrollEffect #prevents overscrolling
```

This requires of course

```
#: import ScrollEffect kivy.effects.scroll.ScrollEffect
```

on top of the kv file.

Answer (score 1):

Below is The rule of the basic ListView:

```
<ListView>:
    container: container
    ScrollView:
        pos: root.pos
        on_scroll_y: root._scroll(args[1])
        do_scroll_x: False
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            id: container
            size_hint_y: None
```

so If you want to access the ScrollView of your ListView, you can do it with:

```
self.container.parent.effect_cls = ScrollEffect
```

Comment: But where do you put this line of code ? Not in the kv file, for sure ?

Comment: @Jean-PierreSchnyder In the kv I will try  `ListView: on_parent: #put it here` but if this does not work I will put it in the python file.